# Nexus Plugin - Type is not assignable to type OutputScalarConfig

Tags: javascript, typescript, plugins, graphql, nexus

I tried to install an official nexus plugin: [Declarative Wrapping plugin](https://nexusjs.org/docs/plugins/declarativeWrapping). This declarative wrapping plugin add an ability to use 'nullable' property, e.g `t.string('optionalField', { nullable: true })`. I followed all the steps explained in the documentation, then re-generate the nexus schema with this command below:

`"generate:nexus": "ts-node --transpile-only src/api/schema"`

the regenerate step succeed, but somehow, it returns an error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '[{ nullable: boolean; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[] | [OutputScalarConfig<"BusinessProfile", "street">]'.
  Type '[{ nullable: boolean; }]' is not assignable to type '[OutputScalarConfig<"BusinessProfile", "street">]'.
    Type '{ nullable: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'OutputScalarConfig<"BusinessProfile", "street">'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nullable' does not exist in type 'OutputScalarConfig<"BusinessProfile", "street">'.

29     t.string('street', { nullable: false });
```

Here is the way I installed the plugin:

```
export const schema = makeSchema({
  types,
  plugins: [
    declarativeWrappingPlugin(),
    nullabilityGuardPlugin({
      onGuarded: ({ ctx, info }) => {
        console.error(
          `Error: Saw a null value for non-null field ${info.parentType.name}.${info.fieldName}`
        );
      },
      fallbackValues: {
        String: () => undefined,
        ID: ({ info }) => undefined,
        Boolean: () => undefined,
        Upload: () => undefined
      }
    }),
    nonNullOptionalFieldPlugin()
  ],
  outputs: {
    schema: __dirname + '/../schema.graphql',
    typegen: __dirname + '/generated/nexus.ts'
  },
  contextType: {
    module: require.resolve('../context'),
    export: 'Context'
  },
  sourceTypes: {
    modules: [
      {
        module: '@prisma/client',
        alias: 'prisma'
      }
    ]
  }
}) as unknown as GraphQLSchema;
```

Perhaps, there is something wrong with the way I installed the plugin, or the command I had to generate the nexus schema, or even probably there's a step missed.